# Using NLTK LazySubsequence with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, nltk

The following code:

```
import multiprocessing
from nltk.corpus import brown

class ParamStruct:
    LS = None

def run_ann(parameters):
    LS = parameters.LS
    print("len(LS): {0}".format(len(LS)))

def main(): 
    corpus = brown.sents()
    LS = corpus[0:250]
    print(type(LS))

    # Prepare parameters for multithreading
    all_parameters = []
    for i in range(1):
        parameters = ParamStruct()
        parameters.LS = LS                  
        all_parameters.append(parameters)

    # Run experiments
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map(run_ann,all_parameters)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

throws the error:

```
<class 'nltk.util.LazySubsequence'>
Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 378, in get
    return recv()
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

Replacing the line `LS = corpus[0:250]` by `LS = line(corpus[0:250])` fixes the issue. Why?

I use Python 2.7.10 x64.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.